# Suitable tool for automation testing of small UI case?

Tags: automated-testing

I need to automate a small process. login change password and logout for approximately 100 users on web application. Can anyone suggest any open source tool which would be able to handle unexpected pop ups as well.

I tried Sikuli but it gets difficult when the pop ups have similar image as the tool recognizes objects based on the captured images.

Comment: To avoid closing, you should mention what are your skills and what you tried so far. Questions which are too open-ended or too wide are closed, because if something requires a book, we are not going to write it, or not write whole app for you (and for free).

Comment: If you like Sikuli's visual approach, try [Kantu](https://a9t9.com/kantu/web-automation). It works just like Sikuli, but inside Chromium, so no wrong matches with elements outside the browser + can run in background

Comment: Note that Kantu is currently (Jul 2017) for windows only.  https://a9t9.com/download

Comment: May this article help you find out the most suitable one, Best Automation Testing Tools for 2018:https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/best-automation-testing-tools-for-2018-top-10-reviews-8a4a19f664d2

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the seleniumIDE, a [firefox plugin](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)

If you outgrow that use selenium with a language binding - ruby, python, c#, javascript, java, etc.
[Check here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#programming-languages)

Selenium is what the browser vendors agree to support and maintain so it is the best choice and underlies most web UI automation frameworks.

Image based processes should be avoided if possible as they are fragile and require more maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs..

If you need these tests run for a longer time, then you should go for open source tool like Selenium IDE (Record and Play) and then once you get the hands on gradually move to Selenium WebDriver.

For a shorter run, suppose say for 1 month or so, try any paid tool's trial version and get your work done.

Some of the good paid tools are Ranorex, UiPath etc.. These will have record and play functionality + so many other advantages; so that you don't even need to worry about the locators.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid using UI automation if you need to do this 100 times.  I suggest using a tool that would make direct web requests.  [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) would both work for this and be much faster and much more reliable than any UI automation.  SoapUI may be simpler if you are unfamiliar with creating web requests.  I prefer Postman, and would recommend it if you are more familiar with web requests and writing code. Both tools offer the ability to record web requests and then play them back, but it's a little simpler in SoapUI to get started.